# Askubuntu mobile-optimised website is difficult to read

Tags: feature-request, design, stackexchange

The current askubuntu.com mobile-optimised website uses a black background and a gray foreground(text). This makes it difficult to read and draws attention away from the important part, i.e., the text itself.

Can the colour combination be changed to something more legible, like a white background and a black foreground or a black background and a white foreground?

This is how the website looks on my Nokia 5530 XpressMusic phone:

[image: askubuntu.com main page, as seen from a Nokia 5530]
[image: A question on askubuntu.com website, as seen from a Nokia 5530]

Comment: It could be useful to know what device you are using, that presents the site in a hard-to-read fashion.

Comment: @GrantPalin, it's a Nokia 5530 XpressMusic phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you given [StackMobile](http://stackmobile.com) a try? It currently only provides read-only access to the site, but it offers a sleek AJAX-based interface to the site that is specially optimized for smartphones, tablets, and mobile devices.

Here's an example of the latest questions on the site and one particular question:

[image]
    
[image]

Comment: this is really nice! much more clearer UI than the screenshots which I have posted. The ability to post answers would of course be a nice addition...Currently, I can use the options button on the top to display the current page on the original askubuntu.com mobile-optimised website and then post answers.

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with your assessment of what the current site is. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

That's what it should look like. It sounds like that's not what you're seeing.

Comment: I have added screenshots to the original question. As you can see, the text is difficult to read. Combine this with the small text size and the difficulty increases.

Comment: @rigved That's because of the Symbian browser youŕe using... ON Android as posted by Oli and on a friends iTouch Askubuntu.com looks like the screenshot above.

Comment: @UriHerrera, ok. i understand.